# Assign List of Vectors to List

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to assign a list of vectors (though each only contains one) to a list.  For example, create list called "eVectors" and do `eVectors[1] = NullSpace[A - eValues[1]*IdentityMatrix[4]]` if there is such a simple way.

Below are three attempts that didn't work, 
where eValues is:
{1.8947, -1.78897, 0.447135 + 0.308371 I, 0.447135 - 0.308371 I}

**(1) In:**

```
eVectors = {};
Insert[eVectors, NullSpace[A - eValues[1]*IdentityMatrix[4]], 1]
Flatten[eVectors]
```

**Out:**

{{}}

{}

**(2)In:**

```
eVectors = List[NullSpace[A - eValues[0]*IdentityMatrix[4]]
   ];
eVectors[[0]]
eVectors[0]
eVectors[[1]]
Flatten[eVectors]
```

**Out:**

List

{{}}[0]

{}

{}

**(3) In:**

```
Array[eVectors, 4]
For[i = 1, i <= Length[eVectors], i++, 
 Insert[eVectors, NullSpace[A - eValues[i]*IdentityMatrix[4]], i]
]
```

**Out:**

{{{}}[1], {{}}[2], {{}}[3], {{}}[4]}

Comment: Does your `NullSpace` expression have any output? It seems that it doesn't. Does `A` have a value at the time of evaluation?

Comment: You will probably want something like this as your final solution: `eVectors = NullSpace[A - #   IdentityMatrix[4]] & /@ eValues`

Comment: @MarcoB A gives {{1, 3, -3, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}.  But you're right, I needed to call like NullSpace[A - eValues[[1]]*IdentityMatrix[4]] instead.

Comment: @image_doctor
Thank you!  Awesomely perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
eVectors = NullSpace[A - # IdentityMatrix[4]] & /@ eValues
```

This solution was proposed in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91910/assign-list-of-vectors-to-list#comment249793_91910) by [image_doctor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/776/image-doctor)

Comment: @Gage When I copy your evalues, {1.8947, -1.78897, 0.447135 + 0.308371 I, 0.447135 - 0.308371 I}, and the A value in the comment, {{1, 3, -3, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}, and then apply the answer I get a list of empty lists. Is this the correction answer?

Comment: @Gage In your original question you refer to eVectors[1] and eValues[1]. This treats those variables as functions. I believe that they are lists and you want to use a double bracket. eVectors[[1]] and eValues[[1]]

Comment: Yes, thank you.  And if you're still getting empty lists, the following is what I had:
eValues = Eigenvalues[A, Cubics -> True, Quartics -> True]; 
eVectors = NullSpace[A - # IdentityMatrix[4]] & /@ eValues;
N[eVectors]